# clarification in nycflight2013

Tags: r, dplyr

Tried to find out avg delay in arrival for the `nycflight2013` data set

```
  flights %>%
  group_by(carrier) %>%
  summarize(avg_dep_delay=mean(arr_delay))
```

but result showing `NA` except one

[image]

Comment: Try `flights %>% group_by(carrier) %>% summarise(avg_dep_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: If you take the mean of a vector that has NA values, you'll just get NA. `mean(c(1,NA, 3))`. Make sure you are only looking at non-missing values when you take a mean.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you need to set `na.rm = TRUE` in your `mean` function. You can use the following code:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
flights %>%
  group_by(carrier) %>%
  summarize(avg_dep_delay=mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 × 2
   carrier avg_dep_delay
   <chr>           <dbl>
 1 9E              7.38 
 2 AA              0.364
 3 AS             -9.93 
 4 B6              9.46 
 5 DL              1.64 
 6 EV             15.8  
 7 F9             21.9  
 8 FL             20.1  
 9 HA             -6.92 
10 MQ             10.8  
11 OO             11.9  
12 UA              3.56 
13 US              2.13 
14 VX              1.76 
15 WN              9.65 
16 YV             15.6
```